# How do I run node-inspector on CloudFoundry?

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I want to debug my node app on CloudFoundry. How do I setup/run node-inspector on Cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately we don't support node-inspector on CloudFoundry.com, it is something we plan to support in the near future but not at this point in time.

I believe it is possible with a private CloudFoundry instance, if you need more information on that then let me know and I can send you the relevant documentation.